# Load local HTML file in webview base on language, use default if file not found

Tags: android, localization, android-webview

I'm creating a webview that will load a local html file base on language selected on the apps. The way i creating this is creating several folder with difference language code "en, ms, cn, fr, etc..." and then change the url base on the getlanguage. `binding.wvAboutUs.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htmls/" + language + "/About_Us.html");` In result, if getLanguage = en, then the url will b "file:///android_asset/htmls/en/About_Us.html" which currently works for me.

However, there might be some case that the htmls file is not available for certain language (and i dont want to put the "default" file into that language folder).

Any idea i can perform a checking - if the url is blank then load the default file. It should be checked File exist for other languages before load default page incase not exist(en html file).

E.g file:///android_asset/htmls/fr/About_Us.html no file found then load the default file:///android_asset/htmls/en/About_Us.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to get it worked

```
AssetManager mg = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream is = null;
try {
  is = mg.open("htmls/fr/About_Us.html");
  //File exists so do something with it
 binding.wvAboutUs.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htmls/fr/About_Us.html");
} catch (IOException ex) {
  //file does not exist
  binding.wvAboutUs.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htmls/en/About_Us.html");
} finally {
 //must close the stream
  if (is != null) {
    is.close();
  }

}
```